# Python C API: import error when using C API

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-c-api

I'm working on integrating Python (via the C API) with an existing C++ application. Things have been going well until I ran into a strange case where I get an import error when running a code snippet through the C API. When I run the same snippet in the same interpreter directly, there is no error.

I am using Window 10, Visual Studio 2010, Python 3.6.10, Qt 5.1.0

Here's what I'm doing via the C API:

```
Py_InitializeEx(0);
PyRun_SimpleString(QString(
    "# allow us to retrieve stdout and stderr messages from C API\n"
    "import sys\n"
    "class OutputCatch:\n"
    "   def __init__(self):\n"
    "       self.data = ''\n"
    "   def write(self, msg):\n"
    "       self.data += msg\n"
    "tdtOutCatcher = OutputCatch()\n"
    "sys.stdout = tdtOutCatcher\n"
    "tdtErrCatcher = OutputCatch()\n"
    "sys.stderr = tdtErrCatcher\n"
    "import zmq\n").toUtf8().data());

m_outCatcher = PyObject_GetAttrString(m_pyMain, "tdtOutCatcher");
m_errCatcher = PyObject_GetAttrString(m_pyMain, "tdtErrCatcher");

QString stdOut(std::move(getOutStr(m_outCatcher)));
QString stdErr(std::move(getOutStr(m_errCatcher)));

qDebug() << stdOut << stdErr;
```

The output I get from the above is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants'
```

When I run the equivalent code snippet in python:

```
# test.py
# allow us to retrieve stdout and stderr messages from C API
import sys

class OutputCatch:
   def __init__(self):
       self.data = ''
   def write(self, msg):
       self.data += msg

tdtOutCatcher = OutputCatch()
sys.stdout = tdtOutCatcher

tdtErrCatcher = OutputCatch()
sys.stderr = tdtErrCatcher

import zmq
print(zmq)
# Uncomment when running directly from Python (not through the C API)
print(sys.stderr.data, file=sys.__stderr__)
print(sys.stdout.data, file=sys.__stdout__)
```

I get:

```
> C:\Python36-32\python.exe .\test.py

<module 'zmq' from 'C:\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\zmq\\__init__.py'>
```

Why would the behavior be different? How should I go about troubleshooting this?

Comment: Are they the same? `import zmq` vs `from zmq import backend`

Comment: `__init__.py`, line 47, in the zmq directory contains the `from zmq import backend` line. My code is just running `import zmq` (`File "<string>", line 12, in <module>` in the backtrace)

Comment: did you find a solution? i'm facing a similar issue

Comment: @jsofri yes, the issue was related to the zmq lib not running in debug mode. If I ran the same test using python_d.exe instead of python.exe, it resulted in the same error

Comment: More information here: https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/issues/1460

Comment: https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/issues/1374